# VSTO create "notification bar"-like message in Outlook

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I'd like to ask my users a simple question if they reply to a particular kind of email, and rather than popping up a `msgbox("Question?",vbYesNo)` style prompt (or a custom form)

I'd like to do it with a notification bar - similar to the one you get when an add-in is disabled:
[image: Notification bar example]

Is this possible?

I don't know if that's what it's called, and I'm struggling to find any documentation online that doesn't relate to android notifications or similar.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do is a top aligned task pane - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2017